# How to Remove default underscore in asp.net while downloading the file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string param = Request.QueryString["id"];
            //int id = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
            //byte[] bytes;
            string fileName;
            SqlCommand cd = DbCon._dbConnection.CreateCommand();
            cd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cd.CommandText = "select id from student_registration where id = '" + param + "'";
            cd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlCommand cmd = DbCon._dbConnection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "select books_pdf from books where id = '" + param + "'";
            // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", param);
            String s1 = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        sdr.Read();
                //bytes = (byte[])sdr["Data"];
                //contentType = sdr["ContentType"].ToString();
                fileName = sdr["books_pdf"].ToString();
                
                    }
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "/";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            //Response.ContentType = contentType;
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName );
            //Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="  +fileName);

           // Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Files/"+ fileName));


            //  Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
```

This is the code where I have written to download the file. but the result what am getting correct file but '/' is replaced with 'underscore;
My question is how to remove that underscore and add '/' in place of underscore I have attached the image please check that and please help me in finding the solution[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfbuT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhcRb.png)
image shows the path stored in database and error what I am facing to download

Comment: The character `/` is not allowed in the file name. Invalid file name characters are `/ \ : * ? " < > |`

Answer (score 0):

fileName = "../librarian/" + sdr["books_pdf"].ToString();

```
                }


        WebClient req = new WebClient();
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.ClearContent();
        response.ClearHeaders();
        response.Buffer = true;
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + Server.MapPath(fileName) + "\"");
        byte[] data = req.DownloadData(Server.MapPath(fileName));
        response.BinaryWrite(data);
        response.End();
```

Proper Selection of File was not given later i corrected proper file location than i got proper output